AWS lambda function .NET Core
When I am migrating the lambda function, it is showing .NET 8 latest version.
AWS lambda function version dotnetcore 1.0 is deprecated, can I migrate it to .NET 8? If yes, then is it required in additional code changes?
Expected output: Need to migrate the lambda function.

What lambda function? What exactly is the problem? Do you get any specific errors? How can we help? Please add more detail and clarify your question.
